# render array with images

Tags: media, navigation, theming

I have this array in PHP

```
$link = array(
    '#type'    => 'link',
    '#title'   => 'link1',
    '#href'    => 'http://www.link1.example',
    '#suffix'  => '<br />',
  );
```

when i call the render() functions i get the correct html

```
<a href="http://www.link1.example">link1</a>
```

How i can change the above render array in order to include an image as a link?

In other words i want this as output from the render() function

```
<a href="http://www.link1.example"><img src='images/link1img.png' /></a>
```

I have tried to use the theme('image',$array) function but when the result of theme() is passed to the render() i don't see the image to my page but the actual html code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-render function for a 'link' element type is [`drupal_pre_render_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_link/7)...looking at the docs, you can pass these parameters:

- #title: The link text to pass as argument to l().
- #href: The URL path component to pass as argument to l().
- #options: (optional) An array of options to pass to l().

You can force a link prepared through `l()` to display HTML by passing `'html' => TRUE` as an option, so you should be able to do the same through the render array:

```
$image = theme('image', array('path' => 'images/link1img.png'));

$link = array(
  '#type'    => 'link',
  '#title'   => $image,
  '#href'    => 'http://www.link1.example',
  '#options' => array('html' => TRUE, 'title' => 'link1'),
  '#suffix'  => '<br />',
);
```

Comment: I tried the above code with no luck. The problem is that in my browser i get that &lt;img typeof=&quot;foaf:Image&quot; src=&quot;http://localhost/drupal/images/link1img.png&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;
It's like the htmlspecialchar() PHP functions runs to my code and does not permit the img to appear!

Comment: I forgot to set the $options. OK now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Better maybe to create a single render array which optionally can be altered through out the render process, ie.:

```
$image = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_formatter',
  '#item' => array(
    'uri' => '/images/link1img.png',
  ),
  '#suffix'  => '<br />',
  '#path' => array(
    'path' => 'http://www.link1.example',
    'options' => array(
      'attributes' => array(
        'title' => 'link1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

renders into:

```
<a href="http://www.link1.example" title="link1"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/images/link1img.png" alt="" /></a><br />
```

If the image has been uploaded using the Field or File module, `image_formatter` can also be used to apply an image style, ie. `thumbnail`:

```
$image = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_formatter',
  '#image_style' => 'thumbnail',
  '#item' => array(
    'uri' => 'public://images/link1img.png',
  ),
  '#suffix'  => '<br />',
  '#path' => array(
    'path' => 'http://www.link1.example',
    'options' => array(
      'attributes' => array(
        'title' => 'link1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

renders into:

```
<a href="http://www.link1.example" title="link1"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://DOMAIN.TLD/sites/SITENAME/files/styles/thumbnail/public/field/images/link1img.png?itok=Bo4ZpxnG" alt="" /></a><br />
```

For more info, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/theme_image_formatter/7